# Free install wizard software

Tags: deployment, installation, release-management

Is there something like [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield) that I can use for free?

Comment: [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: [**See this updated discussion**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941).

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**[WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)**

- **Very powerful and flexible**.
- Can produce MSI packages (Microsoft deployment format of choice)
- **Almost no documentation**
- **Very steep learning curve.**
- XML-based.
- Recommended for very complex installators.

**[Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)**

- Cannot produce MSI packages.
- **Its scripting part looks like INI files structure.**
- Uses Pascal Script based language for extra flexibility.

**[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)**

- Cannot produce MSI packages.
- Fully scripted, very powerful but at cost of high learning curve.
- **Recommened if WiX is too much and Inno Setup not enough.**

**[AdvancedInstaller](http://www.advancedinstaller.com)**

- Basic version is free.
- Can produce MSI packages.
- **Very good user-interface, almost no learning curve to get things done.**
- XML-based (but schema is not very user-friendly, doesn't really matter as you would use GUI editor anyway)
- The best option if you have only basic installer requirements and don't have time to learn something new.

**[IzPack](http://izpack.org/)**

- **Cross-platform**
- Maven integration
- Customizable actions
- Well documented
- Opensource

Comment: I must take a look at WiX; I've used Inno Setup quite a bit, but lamented its lack of MSI support. Then again, I haven't done much development-for-client-side-deployment in a while.

Comment: HM NIS EDIT http://hmne.sourceforge.net/index.php. A Free NSIS Editor/IDE

Comment: for WIX it is a very easy to read book by Nick Ramirez http://www.amazon.com/WiX-3-6-Developers-Windows-Installer/dp/1782160426/

Comment: there is an intrusive licence requirement for inno : http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/is/license.txt I dont know for the rest but this matters lots to corporations.

Comment: I see nothing intrustive about that license. That is applying to the code of inno setup, not your own code. +1 for inno setup -- no books, 5 mins later I had an installer working

Comment: A similar question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546941/129130

Comment: You forgot the most important feature of WIX:  Free

Answer (score 21):

I have been using [Inno Setup](http://www.innosetup.com/isinfo.php) for several years now. It's mature enough that it has a lot of plug-ins. I've found that the forums/newsgroups are very good at answering all the questions I've had so far.

Comment: expect to read the doc first, there's no quick-start or explanation of the model, but once you see how it works it is pretty good

Comment: For a better GUI support over Inno Setup, try http://www.istool.org

Comment: I am adding up to date information to this answer: 
There is Visual Studio extension for writing Inno Setup (and also NSIS) installers directly in IDE. Using the scripting language is even easier (with syntax highlighting, IntelliSense and more):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=unSignedsro.VisualInstaller

Answer (score 12):

NullSoft NSIS http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Answer (score 10):

[WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) (Windows Installer XML) is free.

Comment: WiX works well for us. We like it because it's XML driven and can be easily integrated into our build environment.

Comment: I've dumped InstallShield in favor of WiX just because it became such a hassle to modify installs through a GUI. It is so much easier to open a text file (even though it's in XML) and just make the changes I need.

Answer (score 5):

[Inno Setup](http://www.innosetup.com/isinfo.php) has worked very well as the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) installer for many years.

Answer (score 4):

I googled for "free installer" and found [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/), which I recall that I have used successfully in the past.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Inno.  I was not a fan of NSIS/Nullsoft.

EDIT

the reason I did not like NSIS was the hoops I had to jump trough just to get the version information in the installer title/script.  Basically you have to preprocess the scripts or run the install generator twice.  Maybe they fixed it, maybe not.  But what a hassle.

I also found that the versions of the plugins and the versions of the main component were brittle.  For example, things didn't work well when mixed and matched/upgraded.

We had to keep a specific version of NSIS and the plugins we used in a repository to ensure we had them.

Answer (score 1):

[Nullsoft Installe](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)r is the way to go. It has a bit of a steep learning curve but once you've worked out the scripting you'll have a decent installer in no time. Check out the Eclipse plugin too, it is a great addition.

Comment: wow ... seven other people added NSIS in the time it took me to add my post!

Comment: It's not too steep if you want just a basic installer, it's when you want to add customisations that you start getting to grips with how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) as well.

It's pretty easy to setup installation with prerequisites, has a nice wizard and an editor that let manage the xml scripting from a form.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar solution and found the new kid on the block to be [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/).  Open source, extremely friendly and powerful-looking (I say looking because I never actually finished using it on a project), able to produce installers for multiple platforms.

Actions in particular seemed very easy to set up.

If it were to live up to it's goals, it would easily give the other install solutions a run for their money.

Comment: I added a link to their site.

Comment: Active development of InstallJammer has been discontinued. <-quote from the website

Answer (score 0):

There's the open source [Nullsoft Installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) which began with WinAmp, if I'm not mistaken.

For .NET development you may want to take a look at [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which Microsoft also open sourced. IT's good for those with continuous integration setups.

Answer (score 0):

NSIS (nullsoft scriptable installer system) will do the job. It's open source.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

The [Nullsoft installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is free, powerful and very, very good.

Answer (score 0):

The [nullsoft scriptable install system](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is an open source solution that provides a very powerful and professional install system.

Answer (score 0):

We use [MakeMSI](http://dennisbareis.com/makemsi.htm) here to construct Windows installers. Very steep learning curve, but it's guaranteed to work on any Windows system.

We've had problems with Nullsoft installers in the past, as silent, automated installs (the kind done all the time in managed environments) aren't supported by default.