# Free mulitplatform installer

Tags: installation, cross-platform, izpack

Expanding on [Free install wizard software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137657/free-insaller) I am looking for a cross platform installer.  We support something like 27 platform variations and most of the installers mentioned in the other question are windows only.  We are looking for something portable, possibly java based but I suppose any scripting language would also work.  Suggestions?

Edit:
In order of number of platforms under each OS: linux, solaris, windows, hpux, aix, zlinux, bsd, OSX, OS/360 (I don't care about this one).  So about as much variation as you can get without VMS or mainframe.  A lot of the linux platforms are similar varying only in version of libc.  But we do support 32 and 64 bit on each processor on which the OS runs.  As an example we support 4 solaris platforms:

- solaris sparc 32
- solaris sparc 64
- solaris x86 32 bit
- solaris x86 64 bit

Comment: When you say 27 platform variations, how much do they vary? What are the main underlying OSes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IzPack](http://izpack.org/) ?

Comment: Looks nice but needs a Java VM. Fine if your app's a Java one, or if you assume your users will have a VM installed, otherwise, not so much...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any free cross-platform ones, sorry. I do know that several commercial companies that I know swear by [BitRock](http://bitrock.com/). There's quite a few Linux stacks built with it.

Comment: BitRock looks very nice. Native installer (uses Qt perhaps?) Reasonable pricing (compared with InstallShield) - they even offer reduced pricing for small companies.

Answer (score 3):

If your project is opensource, you can use [BitRock's Install Builder](http://bitrock.com/products_installbuilder_opensource.html) for free. And [this page](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/technote/install.htm) on the wxWidgets site lists alot of different platform installers, describing various issues with each.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/).  Free, open source, and very easy to use while being powerful enough to make just about anything you need.  Supports most platforms out-of-the-box.

Comment: InstallJammer is pretty nice. It produces a native executable whose overhead is minimal (about 1.4MB). It seems to allow pretty extensive customization, unfortunately though via Tcl/Tk.

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest

http://packjacket.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of some: [Open Source Installer Generators in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators).