# Best Windows Installation file Creator?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I'm not the best programmer so I found it was much easier to write a program as several separate executables, which occasionally call each other.  But now I need an easy way to actually run them without writing detailed instructions like Run file one, wait until its completed and no longer in process manager before running file two, file three can be executed 15 seconds after file two has been created. Then Add a key to your registry. Etc.  I figure there must be a good software out there where I can just drop all my exes in, tell it when to run them, and output one file for my clients to run.  Any ideas?

Comment: The best must be a "free" one :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137657/free-install-wizard-software

Answer (score 31):

[Inno Setup](http://www.innosetup.com/isinfo.php) is easy to use, free, open source and scriptable if you need it.

Answer (score 16):

I've always had a good experience with [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

- It's open source
- It has a big community (and hence lots of plugins)
- For simple things, its script-based approach is nice and easy
- It's lightweight and fast

On the downside, if you want to do something more sophisticated, you need to use something that looks a bit like assembly language - very odd, and not particularly pleasant.  Thanks for the comments about that - I'd forgotten all about it!

Comment: Apart from their horrendous assembler-like language. Which they seem to be very proud of, oddly enough...

Comment: The NSIS language isn't that bad.  I remember using it back when I was a newcomer to programming and I didn't have any problems.  There's loads of examples and a very good help file that covers just about anything so it's really just a matter of cut, paste & tweak to do 98% of install tasks.

Answer (score 10):

**[Inno Setup](http://www.innosetup.com/isinfo.php)** is simple, light-weight and covers a lot of ground. I've used it for 5-6 apps over the last 5 years and it never let me down. Highly recommended!

Before that I used InstallShield, which is one of these systems that are so complicated that they "offer" you to "utilize" their "professional services" to create your installations. In other words it's kind of a hack that only managed to build a customer base in the childhood of Windows because there was no competition. It's a bit like a 747 that runs like a Trabant.

The worst, by far, installer product I've worked with is "WISE for Windows Installer". This had me literally smash my mouse in the office floor in frustration. It is (or at least *was*, 4 years ago) utter crap and should be avoided at all costs. This is exactly the kind of software that those pesky license agreements are there for, else the publisher would be sued into oblivion...

Comment: With you on InstallShield. Why did they invent their own language instead of using one of the many actual languages that existed, even at the time?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, two ideas:

- If you're looking for a way to statically put files, registry keys, start menu shortcuts, et cetera on your customer's systems, you should be looking for an installer solution. Many of these exist, and choosing the best one mostly comes down to features and pricing. I happen to like Caphyon's [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/), and it does have a [freeware version](http://advancedinstaller.com/feats-list.html) that looks like it might meet your needs, *except* for the ability to run executables at scheduled times (which would require the Windows Task Scheduler support only found in the Enterprise edition, which is in the ultra-expensive price range, comparable to InstallShield...)
- If controlling the flow of events on your customer's systems is more important than getting the executables on the system, you may want to look into [Automise](http://www.finalbuilder.com/automise-feature-tour.aspx), which is basically an ultra-friendly UI for creating scripts, which makes things like [scheduling tasks](http://www.finalbuilder.com/at-scheduling-projects.aspx) quite easy.

Anyway, you can download trial editions of both pieces of software, to see which one (or possibly both) will allow you to do what you want in the easiest way, or at least give you some ideas on how to best serve your customers. It may turn out that simply adding a new, 'supervisor' executable to take care of registry keys, scheduling, etc. could solve the problem without any third-party add-ons...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any specific requirements apart from being able to install a few executables, then basically anyone will do. I'd recommend [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), not because it is particularly easy to work with (it has a cumbersome assembly-like language which isn't to practical to do more complex things in), but because it is free, has a large and active community, and it generates fast installers with very low overhead. As an extra bonus, you can run the compiler (i.e. the tool which generates the installer) on Linux.

Edit: ...and whatever you do, do **NOT** use InstallShield.

Answer (score 3):

[WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/) is an open source (install shield like) authoring tool that uses the Wix Runtime from Microsoft.

[Wix Tutorials](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/)

Answer (score 2):

The ones I've worked with are:

- InstallShield
- NSIS
- INNO Setup
- Custom created installer

My preference is INNO Setup.  It's free, it's easy.

Comment: dead project at this point

Comment: maybe, but if you are working on POS systems running Windows7, its still just fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

I heart [wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), MSFT's open source, declarative (XML) based toolkit for building MSIs.

It's ace.

If you want to install binaries, add reg keys and even run "custom actions" (have your own code execure during install) you should have a look at it. Then you'll have a one-click (msi) solution. Good eh?

Answer (score 1):

Definately Wix. :)

Wix allows you to do the most things with ease and the difficult things without hacks, it's free and open-source.

You can use Wix within Visual Studio (using Votive) or you can use it using the .Net SDK, MSBuild and your favorite XML editor. Wix supports creating MSI installers, MSP patches, MSM Merge modules, Wix libraries and much more.

Comment: Ease my arse, free of hacks my arse, most brain damaged and overcomplicated software I've EVER dealt with.

Comment: @bviktor I soft-of agree and disagree. WiX is definately a power tool, you need some knowledge on how MSIs work. If this makes it harder or easier is quite subjective, but I can't say it is _that_ hard. For most installations it is a quite straight-forward approach, for complicated stuff you'll be happy to know it will offer each and every feature you'll need.

Comment: It has nothing to do with power or knowledge, it's simply bad design. NSIS is also powerful yet it won't make you pull out your hair.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/). Not only is it free, it's cross-platform and very easy to use. Most common actions don't require any scripting at all, but with a powerful scripting language underneath the hood, you can make an install do just about anything you want.

If all you want is a basic installer to install your application, you can have it built in a matter of minutes from the first time you start it up. If you want something more powerful, the capabilities and documentation are excellent.

Answer (score -2):

If you're not after an installer (which is doesn't sound like you are) Why not just write a program to do what you need?