# Install Python package on offline Windows machine

Tags: python, package, pip

I need to install a package (csvkit) on a windows machine that has no internet connection. However I can get files to that machine through a shared folder.

I know I can use the .tar.gz file to install a package, but the problem is that I see it has a lot of dependencies, most of which are missing too.

Am I reduced to download and install each dependency manually one by one, or is there an automated way to get all the dependencies?

(I know that this question has been asked for Ubuntu, but I can't use this solution for Windows).

Answer (score 1):

If the files are already in their specific folders on the shared folder, you could use an automated installer. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173307/best-windows-installation-file-creator) recommends [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) and [InnoSetup](http://www.innosetup.com/isinfo.php). Both are free.

If the files are extremely scattered or not enough to warrant an installer, then moving them by hand would be the best choice.