# .NET application deployment packages

Tags: .net, deployment, installation, package

It will not be duplication question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137657/free-install-wizard-software)

I am looking for free application deployment package which also allow us to deploy .net framework with them.

So if .net framework is installed it should just install application else intall .net framework and keep installing application without asking user to restart setup.

Most important is **it should generate only single .exe or .msi package not multiple folders with deployment files**.

If anyone knows any solution please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: not entirely sure that exists, in most cases, the .net installation is a completely different install package.  The Microsoft Web Deployment feature for visual studio allows you to build web deployments for your application and will help install .net if its not available on the machine.  But in the end its still up to the end user if they want to install the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The best free option available on the market is [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/about/). It can take a little to learn the scripting but its very powerful and does exactly what you need.

Comment: According to my reading I think Wix also create separate folders for framework and secondly if framework in found we it will install framework but we need to rerun the setup again to install product.

Am I right here or not?

Comment: No, you should be able to have a single executable containing both the prerequisite and your package, using the Burn bootstrapper from WiX. Also, the installation of your main application should continue automatically after the .NET Framework is installed. Here are more details on how to set this up: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm